# When to prefer maximisation of surplus and when instead to prefer minimising differences in price and q to find market equilibrium?

Tags: markets, competitive-equilibrium, surplus

Two alternative approaches to compute a market equilibrium (in static analysis) are either to minimize the differences (either using abs() or a quadratic diff) between supply-demand quantities and prices in a given market or maximise the total surplus.

Which are the advantages of these two approaches and when to prefer one over the other?

I noticed that many partial equilibrium models (e.g. [1](http://www.efi.int/files/attachments/publications/ir_15.pdf), [2 (p 42)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7jnmbKHgQH4C&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=buongiorno+forest+partial+equilibrium+model&source=bl&ots=9VYhnQPRRV&sig=L8Ce1RzJLz6w9AW2q0ct3iMkIDw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil356LlsLSAhVB2hQKHTbLDgwQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=buongiorno%20forest%20partial%20equilibrium%20model&f=false)) use the max surplus method, but I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

Market Equilibrium occurs when the difference between demand and supply is minimized. Equilibrium price and quantity is determined by solving this problem.

Surplus Maximization (or efficiency) is a property that we would want equilibrium to have. First Welfare Theorem says that in competitive markets (in the absence of externalities) market equilibrium is surplus maximizing. In standard demand-supply framework, solving for equilibrium and efficiency yields identical outcomes, and that is why these methods are used interchangeably.

Comment: Absolutely correct.. but it doesn't answer the question.. when (including eventually "technical" reasons) one approach is preferable over the other ?

Comment: Surplus maximization is solving a single optimization problem at the social level whereas finding market equilibrium requires solving multiple optimization problems at the individual level. Solving a single problem can be helpful and saves a lot of time because many terms (like the ones that appears as revenue for some, and the cost for some) gets cancelled when aggregating the objectives.